# Use Amplify Authenticator with non-Cognito identity providers

Tags: aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I have a simple working Flutter application that utilizes AWS Amplify's Authenticator component to register / sign in users using a Cognito user pool.

I'd like to use a local OIDC provider (Keycloak) during development to isolate each developer.

I am not sure if Authenticator component can be used to communicate with anything other than Cognito.  I'm following the [Amplify Auth documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/flutter/build-a-backend/auth/set-up-auth/) and don't see any mention of how to do so.

So my question is, **is it possible for the Authenticator component to interact with anything other than Cognito**.  Pointers to documentation on how to do so, or that indicates that it's not possible, would be great.